# Can ExactTarget and AMPscript use a form to upload an image?

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I would like to have a functionality in my landing page, which user can attach a file within a form. eg:  and insert an image in the data extension. Not sure is this doable or not?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't store the image in a Data Extension since there's no datatype to accommodate it, but you could *possibly* use the [**AMPScript API Functions**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) or the [**SOAP API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) to create [**Portfolio**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/portfolio.htm) item and then store the path in the DE.

Keep in mind that AMPScript and (SSJS) are server-side only, so you'll need some other method to do the uploading.

Also, you'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [**salesforce.stackexchange.com**](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [**marketing-cloud**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [**AMPScript**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.